# "Undefined control sequence. \maketitle" when I add authors

Tags: titles, ieeetran, ieee-style, author-number, ieeeconf

I use IEEEtran style. I am following the [guidelines](https://ras.papercept.net/conferences/support/files/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf). But I get an error when I add the authors names:

```
\documentclass[journal,comsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %optional
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[cmintegrals]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm} % optional

\begin{document}
    \title{test}

    \author{\authorblockN{Michael Shell}\authorblockA{School of Electrical and\\Computer Engineering\\Georgia Institute of Technology\\Atlanta, Georgia 30332--0250\\Email: mshell@ece.gatech.edu}\and\authorblockN{Homer Simpson}\authorblockA{Twentieth Century Fox\\Springfield, USA\\Email: homer@thesimpsons.com}\and\authorblockN{James Kirk\\and Montgomery Scott}\authorblockA{Starfleet Academy\\San Francisco, California 96678-2391\\Telephone: (800) 555--1212\\Fax: (888) 555--1212}}

    \maketitle

\end{document}
```

The error says:

> Undefined control sequence. \maketitle

If I just use `\author{Name}` it works. But I need to use their structure to be able to add affiliations and multiple authors. What is the problem in the script?

Comment: As noted in the comments to David Carlisle's answer, the root problem appears to be that you're using the command `\authorblockN` rather than the correct `\IEEEauthorblockN`. I think this might be because these popular instructions by Michael Shell use the wrong command on page 3: https://ras.papercept.net/conferences/support/files/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misquoted the error message which is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@author ->\authorblockN 
                         {Michael Shell}\authorblockA {School of Electrical ...
l.12     \maketitle

?
```

showing that the undefined command is `\authorblockN`

Looking at the code it seems the commands are `\IEEEauthorblockN` and `\IEEEauthorblockA`

Comment: I posted the error I see using my editor (TexStudioi). But I am using a template and there is no definition for it.

Comment: @seq  Please report that to texstudio it has been reported to them again and again and again that they are scrambling the error messages and confusing users. you could leave a note here https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1068/

Comment: The error appears correctly now. It was my mistake that I was writing the command as: `\and\authorblockA` not `\and \authorblockA`

Comment: It works now. I just noticed that it should be `IEEEauthorblockN` not `authorblockN`

Comment: Plz. add to the answer that `\and\authorblockN` `\and\authorblockA`  should be `\and \authorblockN`  `\and \authorblockA` (space between `\and` and the next)

Comment: @seq a space after `\and` is ignored